# Object in single table cell

Tags: java, sql, database, postgresql

I got a class:

```
 class Person{ 
   String name; 
   String surname; 
   String miasto; 
 }
```

And I would like to put object of this class into a single cell of database table. Is there any way to do this? How?

Comment: Consider reading http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: It'd really help if you could explain what you're trying to achieve with this and why. What's the purpose of jamming that data into one field? Also, which Pg version are you using?

Comment: +1 @CraigRinger for the "Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names" - read that when it was [posted on slashdot](http://developers.slashdot.org/story/10/06/17/2347257/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names). I had completed a multi-country project where our 'system' was affected by several of those Falsehoods, so was an enjoyable read. However, it would be very hard to design a working system (database or otherwise) which can avoid all those falsehoods. Good thing there's **Assumptions** and Pre-conditions to state beforehand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a alternatives to using [`hstore`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/hstore.html) as [mu is too short](https://stackoverflow.com/users/479863/mu-is-too-short) explained, you have `hstore`, composite types, Java-serialized `bytea`, and `xml`.

- a [composite type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rowtypes.html)
- an XML document using the [`xml` data type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-xml.html)
- a `JSON` value using the `json` data type in [Pg 9.2 beta](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/static/datatype-json.html) and it's [9.1-backported version](https://bitbucket.org/adunstan/json_91/)
- [`hstore`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/hstore.html)

I think hstore is probably a better choice, but this is a viable alternative and can be better for some uses. It's hard to recommend one over the other since you haven't explained what you're trying to do and why.

An explanation of each of the options listed above follows.

### Composite type

Composite types are structured and strongly typed, easy to query, quite expressive, fast, and preserve the full capabilities of the type system so you can have all sorts of complex values, arrays, etc in them. However, they're a real pain to query and write in text form from application code, so you'll often land up sending extra queries to work with them.

Don't even think about using them from JPA and other ORMs like Hibernate - you'd think they'd support composite types with their `@Embedded` classes, but you'd be wrong.

It's a truly painful experience to try to add to or alter a composite type once it's in use. Keep that in mind.

```
CREATE TYPE person AS ( name text, surname text, miasto text );

CREATE TABLE some_table (id integer primary key, blah text, this_person person);

INSERT INTO some_table(id,blah,this_person)
VALUES (1,'fred',ROW('a','b','c'));

SELECT (this_person).name FROM some_table;
```

Access with:

```
regress=# SELECT * FROM some_table ;
 id | blah | this_person 
----+------+-------------
  1 | fred | (a,b,c)
(1 row)
```

or, to avoid having to parse composite-type row syntax:

```
regress=# SELECT t.id, t.blah, (t.this_person).* FROM some_table t;
 id | blah | name | surname | miasto 
----+------+------+---------+--------
  1 | fred | a    | b       | c
(1 row)
```

or as a separate SELECT:

```
regress=# SELECT (t.this_person).* FROM some_table t;
 name | surname | miasto 
------+---------+--------
 a    | b       | c
(1 row)
```

### XML

The XML datatype implements the SQL/XML standard. It's rich and portable. SQL/XML offers `xpath` support for querying XML values, you can write some quite complex and powerful queries on structured XML data. XML is easy-ish to work with in most applications, and in Java can be easily marshalled and unmarshalled from native Java objects using [JAXB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-140168.html) and the JAXB annotations.

You don't need any extensions to Java or Pg to use XML.

XML values are structured, but the type isn't, it accepts any well-formed free-form XML document or fragment. Add an `IS DOCUMENT` constraint to disallow fragments. Enforcing stricter structure is a pain. AFAIK Pg can't currently validate XML against XML DSDs or other schema definitions in-database, so enforcing structure requires messy and slow `xpath` constraints.

XML values are not typed, values are stored as strings.

```
CREATE TABLE some_table (id integer primary key, blah text, this_person xml);

INSERT INTO some_table(id,blah,this_person)
VALUES (1,'fred', '<person><name>a</name><surname>b</surname><miasto>c</miasto></person>');

SELECT (xpath('/person/name/text()', this_person))[1] from some_table ;
```

### JSON

JSON is a standard format that's widely understood by many languages and applications. It's fairly easy to work with. The JSON support in Pg is very new, and currently doesn't have any functions or operators for manipulating and querying JSON, so it's pretty opaque to the database right now; you can't write queries like "find me json objects where the 'name' key begins with 'a'". Expect that to improve in 9.3.

JSON support doesn't exist in the core Java SDK, but is available from several libraries, many of which support marshalling/unmarshalling to POJOs via JAXB binding extensions. See, eg Jackson's JAXB support.

The JSON type accepts any well-formed JSON document. It doesn't offer any way to enforce a particular structure. JSON values are typed, but only the limited set of types supported by JSON is accepted, everything else has to be stored as a string.

```
-- in Pg 9.2 and above; for 9.1 use the json91 backport
CREATE EXTENSION json;

CREATE TABLE some_table (id integer primary key, blah text, this_person json);

INSERT INTO some_table(id,blah,this_person)
VALUES (1,'fred', '{"name": "a", "surname":"b", "miasto":"c"}');

-- No easy way to subscript out json values in 9.1, but it's very convenient
-- with any app that has json support.
```

### HSTORE

`hstore` is powerful and gives you lots of good predicates and operators to work with when querying the data. However, the format is non-standard and can be a pain to work with in application code. If using JDBC, `org/postgresql/util/HStoreConverter.java` and the PgJDBC hstore support will help a bit.

The `hstore` type accepts any `hstore` value. Structure may be enforced via `CHECK` constraints. `hstore` values are text; there are no data types in hstore.

```
-- In Pg 9.1 and above; for older versions hstore is available but is
-- added differently. See the documentation.
CREATE EXTENSION hstore;

CREATE TABLE some_table (id integer primary key, blah text, this_person hstore);

INSERT INTO some_table(id,blah,this_person)
VALUES (1,'fred', hstore(ARRAY['name','surname','miatso'], ARRAY['a','b','c']));

SELECT this_person -> 'name' from some_table ;
```

### Serialization to binary in java

Probably the uliest option as the value is completely opaque to the database, but you can also [serialize the value in Java](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/serialization/) and store it as `bytea` in the DB.

Whenever the class changes you have to write custom de-serialization routines to handle the old versions of the class still in the database. No non-java code can work with the value, and you can't query it within the database.

--

It'd really help if you could explain what you're trying to achieve with this and why.

Comment: Good call and thanks for the reminder about PostgreSQL's rich type system.

Comment: @muistooshort Too rich, sometimes; it takes some experience and knowledge to know what to pick for the job. I think `json` is going to take off and become dominant when it equals/exceeds the operator and function support currently available for `hstore`, but right now, it's all trade-offs.

Comment: +1 to storing it as `JSON`. If the data is not going to be searched and can be non-standard, json is convenient. @CraigRinger Wish I could add another +1 for the depth of this answer!

Answer (score 2):

You can serialize an object to a string, and store that.
[From Oracle SDN](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/serialization/)

Comment: Yes i know this is possible, but i dont want to do it that way. Any other proposals?

Comment: Then you probably should have stated that in your question ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using PostgreSQL, you could use [hstore](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/hstore.html):

> **F.16. hstore**
>
> This module implements the hstore data type for storing sets of key/value pairs within a single PostgreSQL value. This can be useful in various scenarios, such as rows with many attributes that are rarely examined, or semi-structured data. Keys and values are simply text strings.

You might have to upgrade your PostgreSQL.

However, for such a simple schema, a three (or four) column table and, perhaps, a foreign key would probably serve just as well.